# TextInputLayout box stroke not showing when TextInputEditText is empty

Tags: java, android, xml, android-textinputlayout

> TextInputLayout box stroke not showing when TextInputEditText is empty
> ![TextInputLayout when TextInputEditText is empty][1]

> After typing some text is works
> ![TextInputLayout when TextInputEditText is not empty][2]

> My XML code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_login_email"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/kPrimaryDarkColor"
                app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/red_primary"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:helperText="example@example.com"
                app:helperTextEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_login_app_logo">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="@={userModel.email}" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> theme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.JayaMaaManakamanaDental" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/kPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/kPrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/kPrimaryLightColor</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

> Color.xml

```
    <color name="kPrimaryColor">#147EDB</color>
    <color name="kPrimaryDarkColor">#134185</color>
    <color name="kPrimaryLightColor">#DEEEF8</color>
    <color name="kButtonColor">#D66D67</color>
```

Comment: Can you share the values of colors you used in your layout? Also please share the XML code for the whole layout.

Comment: Done @SusheelKaram Using constraint layout with scroll view

Comment: But after restarting activity it acts normal @SusheelKaram